# Solve for two variables but output second variable in terms of first variable

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

Here are some equations for illustration:

```
Format[Solve[{4*r1^3 == r2^2*(3*h), 
     t*r2^2*(h - d) == r2^2*(h + d)}, #] & /@ {{h, d}}, InputForm]
```

Here is their solution:

```
{{{h -> (4*r1^3)/(3*r2^2), d -> (4*r1^3*(-1 + t))/(3*r2^2*(1 + t))}}}
```

It is obvious that `d -> h*(t - 1)/(t + 1)` in above equation.

Is there any way to force Mathematica to output the results as:

```
{{{h -> (4*r1^3)/(3*r2^2), d -> h*(-1 + t))/(1 + t)}}}
```

This was a simple example but sometimes equations become too complicated and run for multiple lines. Figuring out a way to express one variable in terms of another will simplify them a lot.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(solh = Solve[{4*r1^3 == r2^2*(h - d + h + h + d), 
     t*r2^2*(h - d) == r2^2*(h + d)}, h, {d}]) // InputForm

(* {{h -> (4*r1^3)/(3*r2^2)}} *)

(sold = Solve[{4*r1^3 == r2^2*(h - d + h + h + d), 
      t*r2^2*(h - d) == r2^2*(h + d)}, d, MaxExtraConditions -> All] // 
    Quiet) // InputForm

(* {{d -> ConditionalExpression[
    (h*(-1 + t))/(1 + t), 
    (r2 == 0 && r1 == 0 && 1 + t != 0) || 
     (r2 != 0 && h == (4*r1^3)/(3*r2^2) && 
      1 + t != 0)]}} *)

sol = {solh, sold}[[All, 1, 1]] // Normal

(* {h -> (4 r1^3)/(3 r2^2), d -> (h (-1 + t))/(1 + t)} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob. :)

Comment: Hi @Bob. I noticed that changing the order of variables I am trying to find changes the final result as well. For example, `h, {d}]` and `d` to `d, {h}]` and `h` results in completely different outputs. Why does this happen?

Comment: `Solve[ ..., h, {d}]` means solve for `h` while eliminating `d`. `Solve[ ..., d, {h}]` means solve for `d` while eliminating `h`. `Solve[ ..., d, h]` means solve for `d` and constrain it to the domain `h`. Since `h` is not a domain, you get a warning and it uses `h` as a variable to be eliminated, i.e., it interprets the statement as if you had entered `Solve[ ..., d, {h}]`. The elimination variable(s) even when just one are in `List` brackets to avoid initially being interpreted as a domain.

Answer (score 0):

As r2 does not appear in your thought for solution, you could first eliminate r2 and then solve for d:

```
Solve[Eliminate[{4*r1^3 == r2^2*(3*h), t*r2^2*(h - d) == r2^2*(h + d)}, r2], d] // InputForm

(* {{d -> (-h + h*t)/(1 + t)}} *)
```